# How JVM handles direct buffers

Tags: java, jvm, garbage-collection, quarkus, direct-buffer

I have a Java application built on the Quarkus framework. Immediately after deploying the application, it consumes a significant amount of direct buffer memory. As illustrated in the screenshot, the *jvm_buffer_total_capacity_bytes* metric indicates that approximately up to 2.5 gigabytes of memory are in use, even when the CPU is idle, and there are hardly any incoming requests.

However, when the application becomes more active, here after 23:00, and the garbage collector begins its hard work, the *jvm_buffer_total_capacity_bytes* metric drops to just a few megabytes.

On another run, I've used jcmd  VM.native_memory to check the native memory diff. Compared to base line taken after a few minutes after start and the highest usage the output is

```
[0x00007fd60cd53d71] Unsafe_AllocateMemory0+0x81
[0x00007fd5f47d9861]
                             (malloc=859648KB type=Other +777122KB #2750 +2443)
```

My question is, why is there a high usage of direct buffer memory when the application is not experiencing a heavy load?

Settings:

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-21.0.0.35.1 (build 21+35-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

-Xms8000M -Xmx8000M -XX:+UseG1GC

with java flight recorder enabled

[image]

Comment: Do you know how the buffers are created? Is it using `ByteBuffer`, the foreign function and memory API, `Unsafe` or something else? Maybe the application is needing the buffers for initialization? Can you try reducing it to a [mcve]?

Comment: @dan1st  jcmd VM.native_memory indicates it is Unsafe, but idk.

Comment: Garbage collection is driven by memory demands, not by memory occupation. It’s not unusual that low activity, which has low memory demands, does not trigger garbage collection, regardless of how much memory has been occupied. To add fuel to the flames, the garbage collector only uses the occupied heap memory to determine whether to run. In the heap memory, a direct buffer is a tiny object.

Comment: @Holger that is what I thought too. However, often the pod is terminated, even though the heap memory hasn't exceeded the Xmx limit. In such cases, it seems that the sole reason for termination is the high usage of direct memory. This observation prompted our investigation and the associated question. By the way, in the screenshot provided earlier, the pod was terminated at 23:09 due to reaching its memory limit of 12 gigabytes.

Comment: What is terminating the JVM? If the limitation is enforced by the os or container, the JVM won’t care about a limit it doesn’t know of. You should set, e.g. `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=…` then.

Comment: Yes, now I'm using MaxDirectMemorySize. lets see if it helps

Comment: It should be mentioned that the newer concurrent GCs might run aside the application even if there are no memory demands.

Comment: @dan1st well apparently it is not the case here with java 21 and G1

Comment: @Urb With new concurrent GCs, I meant ZGC and Shenandoah.

Comment: @Holger setting -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1G didn't resolve the issue. The JVM exceeded the 12G limit even though Xmx was set to 8G, which theoretically should have limited memory usage to no more than 10G. However, the usage spiked to 12G in an idle state after running for 16h, leading to termination by Kubernetes. It appears that there's another factor causing off-heap memory consumption that cannot be controlled and is not visible in any metrics

Comment: you should try using visualvm with buffer-monitor plugin installed on it and try to run your code in local , you might be able to catch where exactly memory is getting allocated off-heap

Comment: So the spikes do not appear in the “JVM Buffer capacity” graph anymore? Did you set a limit on Metaspace?

Comment: @Holger there are spikes but they are as big as defined limit, which I have reduced even further and for now its stable. The next option would be Metaspace, although  VM.native_memory indicates that the Unsafe_AllocateMemory0 is the problem. I think, it is not really possible to limit allocations of unsafe and the app just need a higher limit set to not to crash

Comment: Unsafe_AllocateMemory0  is the symptom, the problem is the caller. The callers should be the manageable components (like the direct buffers). There shouldn’t be any unlimited callers.